# PivotTableJS freezes w/ 5,000 rows

Tags: reactjs, pivottable.js

I'm fetching an array consisting of around 5,000 objects. As soon as I drag in a second field the entire table freezes and the page continues to hang indefinitely. Is there any way for me to handle this volume of data in pivottable?

I've tried the following by slicing the array

1,000 rows, snappy

2,000 rows, slight delay

3,000 rows, increased delay

4,000 rows, major delay

5,000 rows, complete freeze

I've also tried only pulling 3 properties off of each object, reducing the array. This unfortunately had no effect.

Comment: What's this have to do with React?

Comment: I'm using react-pivot-table which is based on pivottablejs, there might be react people that've run in to this.